# JSON to NSMutableArray stopped working in Swift 2.3 iOS 10

Tags: json, swift

I have a code to consume a REST Service but it stop working after update to swift 2.3 and iOS 10. 
I'm getting error in JSON to NSMutableArray Conversion:

```
  class func getStores(latitude:Float, longitude: Float,  completion : (Array<Store>?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let latString: String = "\(latitude)"
    let lonString: String = "\(longitude)"
    var listStores: Array<Store> = []
    let urlFull : String = ConstantHelper.baseURLStore
         Alamofire.request(.GET, urlFull, parameters: ["latitude":latString, "longitude": lonString])
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    if let repoJSON = response.result.value {
                        print(repoJSON)
                        let jsonArray = repoJSON as? NSMutableArray
                        for item in jsonArray! {
                            guard let store = Store(json: item as! JSON) else
                            {
                                print("Issue deserializing model")
                                return
                            }
                            listStores.append(store)
                        }
                        completion(listStores, nil)
                    }
                    break
                case .Failure(let error):
                        completion(nil, error)
                    break
                }
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The error is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

It means that the variable jsonArray is nil. But its nil only in swift 2.3. Because the conversion json to NSMutableArray don't work more. I need to change the way I convert...but how?

There's the repoJSON value

```
(
        {
        cdState = SP;
        cdStore = 100;
        cdZipCode = "04029200                      ";
        mnStore = IBI;
        noAddress = "AV IBIRAPUERA,";
        noAddressAditional = " 3103 - LOJAS 4-5";
        noAddressNeighborhood = " 3103";
        noCity = "S\U00e3o Paulo                                                                                                              ";
        noStore = "IBI-M-C-SHOPPING IBIRAPUERA";
        vlLatitude = "-23.610113";
        vlLongitude = "-46.666505";
    },
        {
        cdState = SP;
        cdStore = 105;
        cdZipCode = "05724900                      ";
        mnStore = JSU;
        noAddress = "AV GIOVANNI GRONCHI, 5819 - LUC001";
        noAddressAditional = "<null>";
        noAddressNeighborhood = "VILA ANDRADE";
        noCity = "S\U00e3o Paulo                                                                                                              ";
        noStore = "JSU-C-C-SHOPPING JARDIM SUL";
        vlLatitude = "-23.630835";
        vlLongitude = "-46.7359";
    },
        {
        cdState = SP;
        cdStore = 107;
        cdZipCode = "05145000                      ";
        mnStore = TTE;
        noAddress = "AV. RAIMUNDO PEREIRA DE MAGALH\U00c3ES, 1465 \U0096 LOJA \U00c2NCORA 1000";
        noAddressAditional = "<null>";
        noAddressNeighborhood = "JD \U00cdRIS";
        noCity = "S\U00e3o Paulo                                                                                                              ";
        noStore = "TTE-PP-C-SHOPPING TIET\U00ca PLAZA";
        vlLatitude = "-23.506182";
        vlLongitude = "-46.718449";
    },
        {
        cdState = SP;
        cdStore = 115;
        cdZipCode = "03153001                      ";
        mnStore = CEN;
        noAddress = "AV.DR.FRANCISCO MESQUITA, 1000";
        noAddressAditional = "<null>";
        noAddressNeighborhood = "VILA PRUDENTE";
        noCity = "S\U00e3o Paulo                                                                                                              ";
        noStore = "CEN-PP-C-CENTRAL PLAZA SHOPPING";
        vlLatitude = "-23.593389";
        vlLongitude = "-46.585574";
    }
)
```

Comment: Why don't you update your question with specific details about the errors? Include the exact, complete error message and point out the exact line causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my code with

```
let jsonArray = repoJSON as! NSArray
```

Instead of

```
let jsonArray = repoJSON as? NSMutableArray
```

and it works great!